# pyspark agg tells me there are wrong chrachters in the column name but the names seem correct

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I use spark 2.3.2 and I want to aggregate 2 columns but the `.agg()` function tells me that there is a problem with the column names but I don't see it.

some peudo code with the actual column names:

```
df = spark.read.parquet('./my_files')

[... doing some stuff with the data everything works fine ...]

df2 = df.groupBy(AD_ID).agg({'pagerank':'sum','pagerankRAW':'sum'})
```

when I do that spark throws me the exception: 
`AnalysisException: 'Attribute name "sum(pagerankRAW)" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\\n\\t=". Please use alias to rename it.;'`
but I don't see the invalid characters .... there are only letters in my column name. When I delete `'pagerankRAW':'sum'` from the `dict` I get the same error but this time for `sum(pagerank)`

so what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a weird one, pyspark should be able to handle parenthesis

I use a different syntax when I use `agg()` though.

I'd use `.agg(sum("pagerank"), sum("pagerankRAW"))` and I don't get this error

I don't think you can use `alias()` with your syntax because I don't see where to place it

With alias `.agg(sum("pagerank").alias("pagerank"), sum("pagerankRAW").alias("pagerankRAW))`

Comment: using `alias()` with the same column name did the trick. One important note though `sum() == pyspark.sql.functions.sum()`